# Dojo updated select no longer triggers onchange event

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.9.  I have a form with two selects (one for salesreps and one for customers), both with onchange events.  Changing the first select causes the second select's options to change (it is reloaded via a php script), that works as it should but then the second select's onchange event no longer will trigger (when changed).   If I only change the second one, I do not change the first one first, its onchange works as it should.   I first got hung on when the new select was loaded it was not a widget, adding the .destroy() and dojo.parser.parse fixed that.  Below is the code for the two select onchange events, can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Maybe there is a better way to reload the second select than totally replacing it with an xhr.get?

```
                    on(registry.byId("salesperson"),"change", function(event) {
                        var resultNode = dom.byId("customer_select_tr");
                        xhr.get({
                            url: "customer_select.php",
                            content: {
                                salesperson_num: dijit.byId("salesperson").get('value')
                                },
                            load: function(newContent) {
                                digit.byId("goal_customer_num").destroy();
                                resultNode.style.display = "block";
                                resultNode.innerHTML = newContent;
                                dojo.parser.parse(dom.byId('customer_select_tr'));
                            },
                            // The error handler
                            error: function() {
                                resultNode.innerHTML = "Your form could not be sent.";
                            }
                        });
                });

                on(digit.byId("goal_customer_num"),"change", function(event) {
                        var resultNode = dom.byId("tab2");
                        dijit.byId("tab2").set("title", "Customer Info55");
                        console.log(digit.byId("goal_customer_num").value);
                        xhr.get({
                            url: "customer_info.php",
                            content: {
                                customer_num: digit.byId("goal_customer_num").value
                                },
                            load: function(newContent) {
                                resultNode.style.display = "block";
                                resultNode.innerHTML = newContent;
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                resultNode.innerHTML = "Your form could not be sent.";
                            }
                        });
                });
```

Comment: Is there a mistake in the second onChange? I mean it should be dijit.byId and not digit, shouldn't it? And why do you use in the first onchange registry.byId and not in the second one? This won't help to fix your Problem but i recognize the difference between the first and the second call. regards

Comment: On your load, you are destroying the second drop down. then recreating it.  Im guessing that the onchange hook is also being destroyed.  You will have to recreate the event listener, or use something like dojo delegate.